# Overlapping in text when using apache FOP to generate PDF

Tags: apache-fop, overlapping

I am having a strange problem while generating the PDF using apache FOP. When I am generating it on a Windows machine, it generates properly.

But when I try to generate this on a Linux machine, some overlapping of the text is observed in the generated PDF. I am using same set of XSLT and input XML files on both the machines. Please refer to the attached snapshot that shows the difference in the generated PDF(s).

Is there any difference FOP performs the transformation when run on different platforms ?

Please provide help here.

Thanks and Regards,
Maneesh Sharma

Comment: Due to less number of reputations I am unable to attach the image.

Comment: **(a)** concerning the image: you could use an image hosting service like [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and put the link in the question; **(b)** consider also adding to the question a minimal FO file showing the problem; **(c)** what version of FOP are you using? is it the same on windows and linux?